# How can I redirect to first tab in modal popup after I close the modal popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popup

```
    <!-- Large modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Login modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    ×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Login/Registration - <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">jquery2dotnet.com</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8" style="border-right: 1px dotted #C2C2C2;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#Login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Login">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                            Submit</button>
                                        <a href="javascript:;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="Registration">
                                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                                <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option>Mr.</option>
                                                    <option>Ms.</option>
                                                    <option>Mrs.</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Mobile</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                                        Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                            Save & Continue</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                            Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="OR" class="hidden-xs">
                            OR</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="row text-center sign-with">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>
                                    Sign in with</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        Google</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My modal popup has two tabs like login & registration, I clicked registration tab then closed the modal popup, after I click the modal popup it is in Registration tab but I want to show login tab. How is it possible?

Comment: here is the demo one   http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VElzQ#comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following code change in JavaScript to show login tab always when click on "Login Modal" button

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

   $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#Login"]').tab('show');
   });
});
```

If you change the HTML structure the above code won't work. It was for tab and you remove tab functionality from [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z7ANK) demo. But still I had fixed your [issue](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z7ANK). Find below

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $('#login-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     $('#login').addClass('active');
     $('#forgetpassword').removeClass('active');
  });  
});
```

Comment: thanks for u replay but after i added your code in js, then i refresh my page it shows model popup automatically.i don't want like that ,i want only when i click on Login Modal display only LOG tab in modal popup

Comment: It is due to '$('#myModal').modal('show');' line. Had removed it. Check Now

Comment: i clicked on forget tab then i closed modal popup but it shows forget tab ony I APPLED  YOUR LOGIC BUT I DID NOT GET IT

Comment: thanks above code is   worked for me but if you observed  it,when i click on login modal popup first it shows forget tab with in fraction of second it goes to login tab , can u solve that issues

Comment: Please change event "shown.bs.modal" to 'hidden.bs.modal'. This will solve your issue.